# IBM worklight 6.1 - Post Worklight server installation , appcenter throwing errors

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I had installed Worklight server 6.1 on WAS 85 full version with derby database. Facing error when after installation trying to access the appcenter.

```
 RequestProces E org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor handleRequest An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open data base.
at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:475)
at com.ibm.puremeap.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:55)
at com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServices.<init>(MobileServices.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:68)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:529) 



Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Provider error. Provider: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:175)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:111)
at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.<init>(PureMeapData.java:180)
at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.PureMeapData.fromDataSource(PureMeapData.java:102)
at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getJPADBStore(DataStoreFactory.java:46)
at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:34)
at com.ibm.puremeap.util.DataUtil.getData(DataUtil.java:453)
... 78 more


Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.util.GeneralException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: wsjar:file:/C:/IBML/WebSphere/PortalServer/wcm/prereq.wcm/wcm/shared/app/ilwwcm-domain-impl.jar!/META-INF/persistence.xml [Location: Line: 3, C: 121]: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.1: Value '2.0' of attribute 'version' of element 'persistence' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'version' has a fixed value of '1.0'.
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parseNewResource(XMLMetaDataParser.java:379)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:318)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:295)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.meta.XMLMetaDataParser.parse(XMLMetaDataParser.java:268)
```

Does anyone else faced the same issue with latest worklight server+ websphere application server 85.

I was able to access appcenter but everything greyed out.

Comment: Tried with Installing Worklight server with DB2 but same error.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the summary of the investigation and some workarounds (which is already tried) that might help.

### (A) Websphere Portal Classloader policy settings:

---

```
Server Classloader Policy (WebspherePortal/server1) = Multiple
Server Classloader Mode = PARENT_LAST

Application (Worklight) Classloader Mode = PARENT_LAST
War Classloader (Worklight) Policy = Module
War Classloader (Worklignt) Mode = PARENT_LAST

WebsherePortal/WCM shared library is applied/associated at Server level.
Worklight Shared library is applied/associated to Worklight Console Application.

Since the shared library of Portal/WCM is mapped at the server level its visible to all the applications installed on the server. So in this case it is available to Worklight Console as well. Also, we have a worklight shared library mapped to worklight console ear and and hence the clash (For JPA related problem I feel that J2EE container automatically finds "META-INF/persistence.xml" which is the portal one).
```

### (B) Possible workarounds:

---

(1) Package the worklight j2ee jar part of the web-inf/lib in worklight console ear so that War class loader loads and it overrides the portal shared library one.

(2) Install Worklight console on a separate server/profile other than WebSphere_Portal.

(3) Since the problem was related to improper .xml files related JPA in the classpath. We can manage this with the below workaround.

```
Steps:

(a) Rename worklight-jee-library.jar\META-INF\persistence.xml to  worklight-jee-library.jar\META-INF\worklight-persistence.xml.

(b) Modify/Add property called "persistenceXmlLocation" in worklight-jee-library.jar\conf\spring-server-core.xml and worklight-jee-library.jar\conf\spring-server-reports.xml files to have "META-INF/worklight-persistence.xml" (or classpath:./META-INF/worklight-persistence.xml).

Note: This is modified so that persistence xml file is picked from within worklight-jee-library.jar.

(c) - optional step - In persistence.xml similar paths (in <mapping-file> tag) should be mentioned for orm.xml files (I believe there are more than one orm files there).

(d) orm.xml file can be removed from ilwwcm-eventlog-jpa.jar.
```

Other references:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14580282

Make sure you correct the question title. It should be Portal Server and not Post server. Also, I believe you are trying to access Worklight console.